# EIP 1559 - Set both priority fee and max fee to the same value

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, transactions, etherscan, ethers.rs

:)

Can someone explain to me how this is possible?

I mean from EIP1559 documentation is it said that if the max_priority_fee + base_fee > max_fee then the max_priority_fee is reduced. (https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees)

In this case:

12.869999013 + 45.87682593 = 45.87682593 (indeed lol) so the `max_priority_fee` should be reduced to 45.87682593 - 12.869999013 = 33.006826917

So it should be:

```
base_fee = 12.869999013 Gwei
max_fee = 45.87682593 Gwei
max_priority_fee = 33.006826917 Gwei
```

But i really don't understand how in this case the guy manage to set the `max_fee` and `max_priority_fee` to the same value.

The hash of the tx if you need more info -> 0xed0f9da824070b042ddadaaaa408f5c53aeabcc5222410bafd2d91c4645a69c7

Btw to let you know, when i create my own tx in rust and set the max fee equal to the priority fee, the priority fee is reduced to match max fee - base fee when i simulate the transaction.

What i want to reproduce is to have the same value in those fields so i will know exactly what i will spend, i know this may not seem to be necessary but this is mandatory for me and my app !

Thank you for your clarification and your help and have a great day everyone.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question

> so i will know exactly what i will spend

you will spend maximum of `maxFeePerGas` or `baseFeePerGas + maxPriorityFeePerGas` if the sum is lower, than `maxFeePerGas`